# how to securely publish logs to the cloud

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, google-cloud-platform

My library is a CLI utility, and people get it by running `pip install [libname]`. I would like to automatically record exceptions that occur when people use it and store these logs in the cloud. I have found services that should do just that: AWS CloudWatch, GCP Stackdriver.

However, while looking at their API it appears that I would have to ship my private key in order for the library to authenticate to my account. This doesn't sound right and I am warned by the cloud providers not to do this.
Example from [GCP](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/tree/master/logging) fails, requires credentials:

```
from google.cloud import logging
client = logging.Client()
logger = client.logger('log_name')
logger.log_text('A simple entry')  # API call
```

While python library exposes source, I understand that any kind of authentication I ship would bear the risk of people sending any fake logs, but this is OK to me, as I would just limit the spending on my account for the (unexpected) case that somebody does just that. Of Course the credentials that ship with the library should be restricted to logging only.

Any example of how to enable logging to a cloud service from user machines?

Comment: you are asking on azure?

Comment: In Azure the relevant service would be Azure Application Insights.

Comment: Side note: Require users to unambiguously opt-in to this behavior.  Enabling it by default would be unacceptable.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Opt-out is worse in your opinion? I am worried about extra friction on asking each user. Don't you think many application already gather a lot of info under the hood without users knowing, just because this information is not critical to anyone? Let's say I would anonymise the data, and exclude things like IP and so on, it ends up with just the OS name, exception and details that are not specific to one user.

Comment: @ikamen opt-out is absolutely worse.  The fact that you are concerned about the friction of asking permission should tell you what you need to know -- people often don't respond favorably to this sort of thing.  Note that you can't exclude IP addresses on the other end of an Internet connection -- when your software phones home, there's a trail of the IP address initiating the connection, at the receive side.  You want to collect info to help you improve the product -- great -- but leave that choice fully and clearly in the hands of the person whose firewall your product is running behind.

Answer (score 1):

For Azure Application Insights' "Instrumentation Key" there is a very good article about that subject here: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/alternative-way-to-protect-your-application-insights-instrumentation-key-in-javascript/

While I'm not familiar with the offerings of AWS or GCP, I would assume similar points are vaild.

Generally speaking: While the instrumentation key is a method of authentication, it is not considered a very secret key in most scenarios. The worst damage somebody can do is to send unwanted logs. They cannot read any data or overwrite anything with that key. And you already stated above that you are not really worried in your case about the issue of unwated logs.

So, as long as you are using an App Insights instance only for one specific application / purpose, I would say you are fine. You can still further aggregate that data in the background with data from different sources.

To add an concrete example to this: [This](https://github.com/Azure/iotedgehubdev) little tool from Microsoft (the specific use case does not matter here), collects telemetry as well and sends it to Azure Application Insights - if the user does not opt out. I won't point to the exact code line but their instrumentation key is checked-in to that public GitHub repo for anybody to find.

> *Alternatively*, the most secure way would be to send data from the
>   browser to your custom API on your server then forward to Application
>   Insights resource with the correct instrumentation key (see diagram
>   below).

(Source: the link above)

App Insights SDK for python is here btw: https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-Python

Answer (score 1):

To write logs to Stackdriver requires credentials. Anonymous connections to Stackdriver are NOT supported.

Under no circumstances give non-privileged users logging read permissions. Stackdriver records sensitive information in Stackdriver Logs.

Google Cloud IAM provides the role `roles/logging.logWriter`. This role gives users just enough permissions to write logs. This role does not grant read permissions.

The role `roles/logging.logWriter` is fairly safe. A user can write logs, but cannot read, overwrite or delete logs. I say fairly safe as there is private information stored in the service account. I would create a separate project only for Stackdriver logging with no other services.

The second issue with providing external users access is cost. Stackdriver logs are $0.50 per GiB. You would not want someone uploading a ton of logfile entries. Make sure that you monitor external usage. Create an alert to monitor costs.

[Creating and managing service accounts](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-accounts)

[Chargeable Stackdriver Products](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/pricing#chargeable-products)

[Alert on Stackdriver usage](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/pricing#alert-usage)

[Stackdriver Permissions and Roles](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/access-control#permissions_and_roles)